# How to redirect the output of "ls-ltr | grep *.txt | cut -1 " to a list in Python

Tags: python, linux

its a fundamental on Linux.I need to redirect the the output of the following to a file or list.

```
cmd="ls-ltr | grep *.txt | cut -1 "
```

My Code is something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

path='/opt/dsoren/'
os.system('ls-ltr | grep *.txt | cut -1 > /dest_path/abc.txt')
```

Any help or insight is highly appreciated.

Comment: So you do have a file names `abc.txt` on your system? What about reading it and using split with the new line character?

Comment: so this command doesnt run on my system

Comment: What are you expecting `ls -ltr | grep *.txt | cut -1` to output? cut defaultly looks for fields seperated by tabs, but you're missing what -1 means (field?). `*.txt` won't expand like a glob would (and will probably look for a file called '*.txt'.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the builtin functions?

```
import glob
import os
sorted(glob.glob('./*.txt'), key=os.path.getmtime)
```

Comment: Agreed. Most times that you find yourself using os.system there is a far more readable and robust pure Python solution; os,system always reads as a hack. Furthermore `ls` is designed to make human readable output and thus is obnoxiously difficult to parse correctly (but you knew that).

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Use Python's included batteries instead of the shell.

**Long answer**

**1. Fix command**

First, your shell command doesn't do anything meaningful. The `grep` and `cut` commands are not needed here, and won't do what you expect here. In the following, I assume you meant to do this:

```
cmd='ls -1tr *.txt'
```

Note that I'm using `-1` instead of `-l` to get just the file names without having to `cut` anything.

**2. Run from Python and parse result (unsafe!)**

You can run the command from Python via `subprocess`, using the `communicate()` method of `Popen`. Then, strip the trailing newline on the result `out`, and split it by newlines. This leads to a list of strings `files` which contains your filenames:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess

# This is unsafe!

cmd='ls -1tr *.txt'

out, err = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()
files = out.rstrip('\n').split('\n')

print repr(files)
```

**3. How to do it correctly**

While the script above answers precisely your question, it will fail horribly if your file names contain newlines or other strange stuff. This is not so much a practical issue, but can easily become a security issue!

The correct way to do this is without any shell. Just use Python's included batteries, which are **safe** and **simpler**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import glob
import os.path

unsorted_files = glob.glob('*.txt')
files = sorted(unsorted_files, key=os.path.getmtime)

print files
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use

```
fp = os.popen('ls -lr')
```

which returns a file descripter in `fp`.

You can itterate throuch each line:

```
 for l in fp.readlines():
    print l
```

Answer (score 0):

I thik problem is with your cut argument

In [4]: os.system('ls-ltr | grep *.txt | cut -1 > abc.txt')
sh: 1: ls-ltr: not found
cut: invalid option -- '1'

Try 'cut --help' for more information.

you can try this

In [9]: os.system('ls -ltr | grep *.txt | head -1 > pqr.txt')

Out[9]: 0

This will working fine.First try at terminal then use in your program